ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stubs.profiler' while import stub files in PyCharm
In Pycharm, I am trying to import stub files(.pyi file) in .py file, but I get error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stubs.profiler'.
My file structure is as follows:

In profiler.py, I try to use import stubs.profiler to get defined classes and functions, but I get error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stubs.profiler'.
My file content is as follows,

Could anyone help me?

put your content here and not in links and images

So, are you satisfied with one of the answers? If yes, please mark them as the answers on both of your questions. If not, please peovide, what else do you want to be clarified?

Stub files (.pyi) are there, so that PyCharm and other tools can display for your .py files the correct types of variables, return values, function arguments etc. They are not meant to be imported or in other way used by python interpreter itself in any way.

You can Either move the "stubs" folder to your present working directory of the main file or you can run the desired .py file from any path by writing the following code in the file:
import sys
sys.path.append("Complete path to stubs folder")
import profiler

